# Getting a Field List from a DBExpress TSQLQuery

Tags: delphi, dbexpress, fieldlist

I am having a problem getting a list of fields from a query defined at run time by the users of my program.  I let my users enter a SQL query into a memo control and then I want to let them go through the fields that will return and do such things as format the output, sum column values and so forth.  So, I have to get the column names so they have a place to enter the additional information.

I would do fine if there were no parameters, but I also have to let them define filter parameters for the query.  So, if I want to set the parameters to null, I have to know what the parameter's datatype is.

I am using Delphi 2006. I connect to a Firebird 2.1 database using the DBExpress component TSQLConnection and TSQLQuery. Previously, I was successful using:

for i := 0 to Qry.Params.Count - 1 do Qry.Params[i].value := varNull;

I discovered I had a problem when I tried to use a date parameter. It was just a coincidence that all my parameters up until then had been integers (record IDs).  It turns out that varNull is just an enumerated constant with a value of 1 so I was getting acceptable results (no records) was working okay.

I only need a list of the fields.  Maybe I should just parse the SELECT clause of the SQL statement.  I thought setting Qry.Prepared to True would get me a list of the fields but no such luck.  It wants values for the parameters.

If you have an idea, I would sure like to hear it.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replied again 'coz I'm interested. My methods works (with my queries) because they have been pre-defined with the params' datatypes preset to the correct type:)

I'm not sure how you are expecting the query to know or derive the datatype of the param given that you are not even selecting the field that it operates against.

So I think your query setup and user input method will need more attention.  I've just looked up how I did this a while ago. I do not use a parameterised query - I just get the "parameter values" from the user and put them directly into the SQL. So your sql would then read:

SELECT s.hEmployee, e.sLastName
      FROM PR_Paystub s
      INNER JOIN PR_Employee e ON e.hKey = s.hEmployee
      WHERE s.dtPaydate > '01/01/2008'

therefore no parameter type knowledge is necessary. Does not stop your users entering garbage but that goes back to input control :)

Answer (score 2):

Although a slightly different dataset type this is what I use with TClientDataset simple and effective :)

```
for i := 0 to FilterDataSet.Params.Count -1 do  
begin  
 Case FilterDataSet.Params.Items[i].Datatype of  
    ftString:  
    ftSmallint, ftInteger, ftWord:  
    ftFloat, ftCurrency, ftBCD:  
    ftDate:  
    ftTime:  
    ftDateTime:  
    .  
    .  
    . 
end;
```

end;
can you not do something similar with the query?

Answer (score 2):

You guys are making this **way** too hard:

```
for i := 0 to Qry.Params.Count - 1 do begin
    Qry.Params[i].Clear;
    Qry.Params[i].Bound := True;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what version of Delphi you are using. In the Delphi 2006 help under Variant Types, it says:

> Special conversion rules apply to the
>   Borland.Delphi.System.TDateTime type
>   declared in the System unit. When a
>   Borland.Delphi.System.TDateTime is
>   converted to any other type, it
>   treated as a normal Double. When an
>   integer, real, or Boolean is converted
>   to a Borland.Delphi.System.TDateTime,
>   it is first converted to a Double,
>   then read as a date-time value. When a
>   string is converted to a
>   Borland.Delphi.System.TDateTime, it is
>   interpreted as a date-time value using
>   the regional settings. When an
>   Unassigned value is converted to
>   Borland.Delphi.System.TDateTime, it is
>   treated like the real or integer value
>   0. Converting a Null value to Borland.Delphi.System.TDateTime raises
>   an exception.

The last sentence seems important to me. I would read that as varNull cannot be converted to a TDateTime to put into the field, and hence you get the exception that you're experiencing.

It also implies that this is the only special case.

Couldn't you do something like:

```
for i := 0 to Qry.Params.Count - 1 do 
begin
  if VarType(Qry.Params[i].value) and varTypeMask = varDate then
  begin
    Qry.Params[i].value := Now; //or whatever you choose as your default
  end
  else
  begin
    Qry.Params[i].value := varNull;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was this:

```
sNull := 'NULL';
Qry.SQL.Add(sSQL);
for i := 0 to Qry.Params.Count - 1 do begin
  sParamName := Qry.Params[i].Name;
  sSQL := SearchAndReplace (sSQL, ':' + sParamName, sNull, DELIMITERS);
end;
```

I had to write SearchAndReplace but that was easy.  Delimiters are just the characters that signal the end of a word.

Answer (score 0):

```
TmpQuery.ParamByName('MyDateTimeParam').DataType := ftDate;
TmpQuery.ParamByName('MyDateTimeParam').Clear;
TmpQuery.ParamByName('MyDateTimeParam').Bound := True;
```